# How can I block touching outside from opening linearlayout?

Tags: java, android, android-theme

I mean I create a android app.
And I call a activity from my main actity.My new activty type :  `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"` 
I success it. but when new activty come I click outside and it closing.I do not want this. I block touching outside. How can i do this? 
thanks.

Comment: show your code - then one may be able to help!

Comment: How about using a Dialog rather than Activity for your popup?